# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/StandardBasicTypes - What could be the reason?

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, jodatime

I have the following entity with Joda time.

```
@Column(name = "CLASS_START_DT")
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime classStartDate;

@Column(name = "CLASS_END_DT")
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime classEndDate;
```

It compiles well. No issues. But when I run the code, when inserting data into this Entity, it throws the error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/StandardBasicTypes
   ...
   ..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Pom.xml entries:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried 1.3 version as well. Using hibernate 3.2.

Don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

`org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes` is not available for Hibernate before version 4.0. Try  upgrading your version of Hibernate

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: We use JBoss 4.x, which uses Hibernate 3.2. So we are stuck, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes, you need a version of hibernate 3.6 (I recommend you 3.6.10) or up. With versions lower it does not found good.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```